# return canvas as webp image

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

How can I return the canvas on this function as a webp image?

```
function capture(video) {
    if(scaleFactor == null){
        scaleFactor = 1;
    }
    //var w = video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
    //var h = video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
    var w = 700;
    var h = 400;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width  = w;
        canvas.height = h;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
        var uniq = 'img_' + (new Date()).getTime();
        canvas.setAttribute('id', uniq);
    return canvas ;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Canvas has a method known as `.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions)`.

I this case the following snippet should suffice

```js
canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
```

This will give you a data url which is a base64 encoding of the image and will look something like

```
data:image/webp;base64,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
```

More information for this can be found on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: Can you exemplify the implementation based on my code?

Comment: @btgen You would simply need to return the canvas.toDataUrl  instead of the canvas. This data url will work for the src parameters in modern browsers in image tags.